# Convert Long And Lat to X Y coordinate using ArcGis Api For Javascript

Tags: javascript, gis, arcgis-js-api

Hello i'm trying to convert long,lat values to X,Y using ArcGis Api For Javascript

```
 var i = esri.geometry.lngLatToXY(3.13, 36.742)
 console.log(i); //returns Array [ 348541.32567373366, 4403205.668961807 ]
```

in what system does this conversion take place?
is there a method to specify the projection system?

note: the conversion is done from decimal degree to meters

i followed this : 
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.geometry.webmercatorutils-amd.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This method is used to convert geographic coordinate system longitude/latitude (wkid 4326) to projected coordinate system Web Mercator (wkid 102100).

Default esri map use Web Mercator as projection system. If you need to convert your coordinates to an other coordinate system you need to use the `project` method of GeometryService :
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/geometryservice-amd.html

Example:

```
require(["esri/geometry/Point", "esri/tasks/GeometryService", "esri/tasks/ProjectParameters", "esri/SpatialReference", "dojo/domReady!"],
  function(Point, GeometryService, ProjectParameters, SpatialReference) {

    var outSR = "YOUR_OUTPUT_COORDINATE_SYSTEM"; // `wkid {number}`
    var geometryService = new GeometryService("https://utility.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");
    var inputpoint = new Point({
      longitude: "YOUR_LONGITUDE_INPUT",
      latitude: "YOUR_LATITUDE_INPUT"
    });

    var projectParams = new ProjectParameters();
    projectParams.geometries = [inputpoint];
    projectParams.outSR = new SpatialReference({ wkid: outSR });

    geometryService.project(projectParams, (result) => {
      let outputpoint = result[0]; // outputpoint first element of result array
      console.log("Result x:", outputpoint.x, "y :", outputpoint.y);
    });
  });
```

Wkid numbers can be found here:

- projected coordinate system: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Projected_coordinate_systems/02r3000000vt000000/
- Geographic coordinate system: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Geographic_coordinate_systems/02r300000105000000/

**EDIT**

Here is a working example: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2polEtt6siYbjk3kOZ29?p=preview)

Comment: i'm using the 3.22 version of arcgis  js api .. and i changed : esri/geometry/SpatialReference ->esri/SpatialReference and esri/tasks/support/ProjectParameters -> esri/tasks/ProjectParameters  but i have a problem with GeometryService and the console log is "TypeError: GeometryService is not a constructor"

Comment: @BKam 
I edited my answer to correct and add a working example! It was an old piece of code as I am using JS API 4.x yet.